# How to validate multiple Ajax loaded Partial Views?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View, `Contact`, that loads `n` number of `Caller` partial views, `m` number of `Child` partial views, and one `CallNote` partial view all loaded via Ajax once the document is ready.

I'm able to add and remove `Callers` and `Children` too, so these numbers are not static.

`Contact.cshtml`, with some stuff removed:

```
@using Birth_To_Five.ViewModels
@model CallDetailViewModel

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Call Detail</a></li>
        @* Other tabs not shown here *@
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitCallDetailsAsync", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="well">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CallThreadViewModel.Id)
                    <span style="color: red">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary()
                    </span>
                    @* Call Details *@
                    <div class="row">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Call Details</legend>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnteredByEmail, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EnteredByEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredByEmail, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Who took the call" })
                        </div>
                        @* Other stuff *@
                    </div>
                    @* Caller Details *@
                    <div class="row">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Callers</legend>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    @* Render each existing caller. Each caller gets their own well to create a visual separation between them. *@
                    @foreach (var callerViewModel in Model.CallerViewModels)
                    {
                        <div class="progress" id="callerLoadingBar-@callerViewModel.Id" data-callerid="@callerViewModel.Id" data-calldetailid="@Model.Id">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">Loading Caller...</div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div id="newCaller"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        @* Button to search for and add a caller *@
                    </div>

                    @* Children Details *@
                    <div class="row">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Children</legend>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    @* Render each existing child. Each child gets their own well to create a visual separation between them. *@
                    @foreach (var childViewModel in Model.ChildViewModels)
                    {
                        <div class="progress" id="childLoadingBar-@childViewModel.Id" data-childid="@childViewModel.Id" data-calldetailid="@Model.Id">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">Loading Child...</div>
                        </div>
                    }

                    <div id="newChild"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        @* Button to search for and add a child *@
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" id="callNoteLoadingBar">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">Loading Call Note...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/calldetailscripts")
}
```

Snippet from my JS script, `callDetailFunctions`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    getCallNote('#callNoteLoadingBar', $('#Id').val());
    getAllCallers();
    getAllChildren();
});

// function getAllWhatever(){ Foreach loading bar, addCaller/Child/CallNotePartialView(..., ..., ..., etc.); }

function addWhateverPartialView(divToReplace, thingIWantId, callDetailId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetWhateverPartialViewAsync',
        data: {
            thingIWantId,
            callDetailId
        },
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + xmlHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(divToReplace).replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here in my `HomeController` I have the `SubmitCallDetailsAsync` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitCallDetailsAsync(CallDetailViewModel callDetailViewModel)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext))
    {
        // Call Details
        var callDetailServices = new CallDetailServices();
        await callDetailServices.AddOrUpdateCallDetailFromCallDetailViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Callers
        var callerServices = new CallerServices();
        await callerServices.AddOrUpdateCallersFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Children
        var childServices = new ChildServices();
        await childServices.AddOrUpdateChildrenFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Call Note
        var callNoteServices = new CallNoteServices();
        await callNoteServices.AddOrUpdateCallNoteFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Check the model state (returns true if it's good, false otherwise.
        // Also spits out some debug text for me to tell me what broke the Model)
        if (!UtilityServices.CheckModelState(ModelState))
        {
            callDetailViewModel.DirectionChoices =
                await unitOfWork.DirectionChoiceRepo.GetAllAsSelectListItemsAsNoTrackingAsync();

            return View("Contact", callDetailViewModel);
        }

        await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
    }           

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The gist of what's happen is that I have a loading bar as a placeholder for each `Caller`, `Child`, and the `Call Note` and then when the document loads I go and get those on `$(document).ready()`

My problem is that when I submit `Contact.cshtml` and hit a model validation error I get sent back to my `Contact` page, which reloads all the `Callers`, `Children`, and the `Call Note`, thus losing all changes.

What should/can I do to handle this scenario?

Comment: and what is your expected result? if part of the data is wrong do you still want to save the rest?

Comment: If, say, there was a model validation error in one of the `Callers` or any number of the partials, I would like to return to the `Contact` view with the same information I submitted and for the validation messages to appear in their respective areas or at least in the validation summary.

Comment: in C# code you can check `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to know when to redirect or not. Also when your model state is not valid, you need to pass current model to the view (even if it has errors). If you create a new one instead, this will blank all fields. But it's not possible to answer your question properly because it's missing relevant code for reproducing the issue.

Comment: @derloopkat I've added my `SubmitCallDetailsAsync` function, as I think that's what was missing from my code that you were hinting at. I'm giving the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` a try in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [deloopkat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610327/how-to-validate-multiple-ajax-loaded-partial-views?noredirect=1#comment88260684_50610327), I was able to get this working (for the most part)

I changed my `Contact` page to use `Ajax.BeginForm()` and added a `partialCallDetail` id to the section I want to replace with a Partial View result:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitCallDetailsAsync", "Home", new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "partialCallDetail", OnSuccess = "onSuccess"})) @* <----------- Note the UpdateTargetId *@
{
    <div class="well">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CallThreadViewModel.Id)
        <span style="color: red">
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </span>
        @* Call Details *@
        <div id="partialCallDetail"> @* <------------------ This whole div gets replaced by the Submit function when the Model Validation fails *@
            @* All of the same stuff as before in my original post *@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function onSuccess(data) {
            ///<summary>
            /// When the Ajax form is submitted, this function gets called with the return data.
            /// Determine if it contains a redirectUrl and go there if it does
            ///</summary>
            if (data.redirectUrl !== undefined) {
                window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

I created a separate Partial View, `_PartialCallDetail`, that renders each `Caller`, `Child`, and `CallNote`s PartailView on the spot rather than calling a function via Ajax on `$(document).ready()`

```
...
@* Render each existing caller. Each caller gets thier own well to create a visual seperation between them. *@
@foreach (var callerViewModel in Model.CallerViewModels)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCallerInfo", callerViewModel);
}
...etc.
```

I then changed my Submit function to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitCallDetailsAsync(CallDetailViewModel callDetailViewModel)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext))
    {
        // Call Details
        var callDetailServices = new CallDetailServices();
        await callDetailServices.AddOrUpdateCallDetailFromCallDetailViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Callers
        var callerServices = new CallerServices();
        await callerServices.AddOrUpdateCallersFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Children
        var childServices = new ChildServices();
        await childServices.AddOrUpdateChildrenFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Call Note
        var callNoteServices = new CallNoteServices();
        await callNoteServices.AddOrUpdateCallNoteFromCallDetailsViewModelAsync(callDetailViewModel, ModelState, unitOfWork);

        // Check the model state
        if (!UtilityServices.CheckModelState(ModelState))
        {
            // Setup all drop downs
            callDetailViewModel.DirectionChoices =
                await unitOfWork.DirectionChoiceRepo.GetAllAsSelectListItemsAsNoTrackingAsync();

            foreach (var callerViewModel in callDetailViewModel.CallerViewModels)
            {
                await callerServices.SetupSelectListItemsAsync(callerViewModel, unitOfWork);
            }

            foreach (var childViewModel in callDetailViewModel.ChildViewModels)
            {
                childViewModel.SexChoices = await unitOfWork.SexChoiceRepo.GetAllAsSelectListItemsAsNoTrackingAsync();
            }

            // Return the ViewModel with Validation messages
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView("_PartialCallDetail", callDetailViewModel);
            return View("Contact", callDetailViewModel);
        }

        await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
    }

    return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", null) });
}
```

Now when there is a Model Validation error, I send back my `_PartialCallDetail` view, which updates the `Contact` page with the existing data and activates the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)`s

---

I think it's important to note that this isn't perfect in it's current state:

- I now have two Views, `Contact` and `_PartialCallDetail`, that I need to update if I make a design change in the future.
- The `@Html.ValidationSummary()` I have in my View is only for non-Ajax content, so the User's have to sift through the View to see what's wrong.
- And a couple other specific-to-my-code issues too, but I'll leave those out.

But I feel pretty good that this is a step in the right direction